# Creating different matrix by same matrix-matrix multiplication inside loop using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a square matrix of dimension n*n. I have to define a function which takes this matrix `A` as input and also a value `k`. 
Matrix A is random matrix generated by numpy random function.
Suppose k=4 then we have to produce three different matrices such that:

```
 matrix_2=A*A
 matrix_3=A*A*A
 matrix_4=A*A*A*A
```

Where all multiplication above are matrix multiplication( where columns A = Row of B), not element wise multiplication.

k can have any value given by user. How can we implement this using for loop in python.

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Simple implementation of what you described should work. Incase you are stuck in some part ask that part only.

Comment: Okay. I will keep in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list` or `dict` for a variable number of variables. In this case, you can use a dictionary comprehension, with dictionary keys aligned with the power:

```
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power

np.random.seed(0)

n = 2
A = np.random.random((n, n))

def make_arrays(arr, k):
    return {i: matrix_power(arr, i) for i in range(1, k+1)}

res = make_arrays(A, 4)
```

Result:

```
{1: array([[0.5488135 , 0.71518937],
           [0.60276338, 0.54488318]]),
 2: array([[0.73228622, 0.78220024],
           [0.65924031, 0.72798764]]),
 3: array([[0.87337022, 0.94993107],
           [0.80060427, 0.86814988]]),
 4: array([[1.05190103, 1.14222656],
           [0.96267139, 1.04562393]])}
```

Comment: This is element wise multiplication, what I meant is matrix multiplication.

Comment: does np.matmul(a,b) also means the same thing ?

Comment: For matrices, yes. But read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) to find the differences vs `np.dot` / `@`, which are the more common operations.